# Accessibility testing the web for the blind and low vision in Linux

Tags: accessibility

Windows has Jaws. Mac desktop and iOS has VoiceOver. What is the equivalent in the Linux world?

I'm willing to even load another desktop manager if need be. I currently use Cinnamon 2.x on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Orca Screen reader is preinstalled, launch it by `orca` or searching dash for `orca`. See the [wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/Orca?action=show&redirect=Orca) for it.